# Is there a way to remove the webfont load in this site?

Tags: wordpress

Here's the gtmetrix url: https://gtmetrix.com/reports/wp-demo.us/xmC4AULL. I've optimized most parts however I cannot remove the webfont error at the second line of the waterfall chart.

Answer (score 0):

Download fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0 from http://www.tegalsari-ubud.com/assets/tegalsarinew/font-awesome-4.7.0/fonts/

(the last file in the directory).

Upload it to the /wp-content/themes/boxwp/assets/fonts/ folder on your server

If you want to remove the load itself then you will need to find the line that calls it in the boxwp theme and delete it.